# Renew local certificates for local Sitecore XC and XP instances

Tags: sitecore-commerce, certificate

I want to update expired local certificates for my local Sitecore Commerce and CMS instance but don't want to change thumbprint.

What is the procedure to do this

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more than a generic SSL or IIS question, not a Sitecore one. but from StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440806/how-to-renew-an-iis7-self-signed-ssl-certificate simple answer is -

**No, it's not possible.**

Because you have chosen to use a self-signed certificate that you have explicitly configured to be trusted in your client. If you replace that certificate with a new one with different validity dates (even with the same keys, although it's probably best to change the keys too), it will be a different certificate. Being different, it won't be the same as the one you had imported in your clients in your initial set up (logically).

---

If you want to be able to do silent renewals, then you need a **self-signed CA certificate**. You emit certificates for your server(s) from that CA, and you ask your clients to trust that CA.

The second and better option is that next time you produce a self-signed certificate, make it **long-lived**. Certificates expire mostly in order to make revocation work (certificate expiry prevents CRL from growing indefinitely). For a self-signed certificate, there is no revocation, so you can make the certificate valid for 20 years or more. I personally think with the Sitecore local environment setup we should have the option to choose "certificate valid for" time.